# Mismatched or Mismatching?

Tags: grammar

I'm writing a program reporting differences between files, the report contains a summary list where one item describes how many files are different by some attribute (eg. timestamp, size, content).

I wrote `3 mismatching timestamps` but using Google translator I get `3 mismatched timestamps`

So now I'm not sure what phrase is correct

Comment: Consider using [unmatching](https://www.lexico.com/definition/unmatching). If something is mismatched, the intended replacement isn't right, or a spare part is incorrect, so the question needs some context. However, [unmatched](https://www.lexico.com/definition/unmatched) has a different meaning.

Comment: I'd use **nonmatching**, but I don't think there's a single right and wrong word.

Comment: In reply to the other comments, I am a computer programmer and in my experience "mismatch" is commonly used in computer science scenarios like the one being described. I don't think there is a need to change the prefix.

Comment: I have seen both "mismatching" and "mismatched" used in this kind of use case, and it is mostly a matter of personal preference. I would probably choose "mismatching" personally, but I do not think there is a "correct" choice between the two.